# PHP string comparison difficulty

Tags: php, file-io

I'm attempting to help a friend with a php programming assignment. He needs to read passwords and usernames from a file and compare them to a username ($user) and password ($password) entered from a form to authenticate a user. (simple, no security whatsoever, just academic)

The problem is the comparison of strings. I've gone back and forth between using ==, ===, and strcmp but nothing seems to work correctly. Any Ideas?

This is the text file that's being read:

UserData.txt

```
test:pass
testa:pass2
testb:pass4
testc:pass6
```

---

```
<?php

$fh = fopen("UserData.txt", "r") or die("Can't open file");

$line = "";
$line_length = 0;
$div = 0;
$accounts = array();

while($line = fgets($fh)) {
    $div = strpos($line, ":"); //positing of ":" dividing username and password
    $line_length = strlen($line); //Total length of username + : + password line entry

    $accounts[substr($line, 0, $div)] = substr($line, $div + 1, $line_length);
}

foreach ($accounts as $key => $value) {
    if(($user === $key) && ($password === $value)) {
        echo "MATCH - user/pass correct<br/>";
        //Just needs to echo the above line if user/pass correct
    }
}

?>
```

HTML File:

```
<form name="myform" method="GET" action="login.php">
Please Login to order
User Name:
<input type="text" name="user" value="" size="10"/>
Password:
<input type="password" name="password" value="" size="10"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" >
```

Updated login.php file:

```
<?php

$lines = file('UserData.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  $arr = explode(':', $line);
  if ($arr[0]==$user && $arr[1]==$password)
  {
     echo "MATCH - user/pass correct<br/>";
  } else {
     echo "NO<br />";
  }
}

echo "<br />";
var_dump($user);
echo "<br />";
var_dump($password);
echo "<br />";
echo phpversion();
?>
```

Output:

```
NO
NO
NO
NO

string(4) "test" 
string(4) "pass" 
4.4.9
```

Comment: Are `$user` and `$password` being assigned to the respective `$_POST` form fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As short as this :

```
$lines = file('UserData.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
  $arr = explode(':', $line);
  if ($arr[0]==$user && $arr[1]==$password)
  {
     echo "MATCH - user/pass correct<br/>";
  }
}
```

If file UserData.txt is huge, increase memory to handle

Comment: If the file is huge, you'd be better off reading it on a line-by-line basis than increasing memory.

Comment: If the file is small, i'd better to stay with this function because this is a homework

Comment: @ajreal, I like this implementation - it's clean and concise. But for some reason I can't seem to understand why, when a correct username/password is entered into the form the "$arr[0]==$user && $arr[1]==$password" doesn't return true. I've added the form that calls this php script to the main post. Any ideas?

Comment: replace `$user` to `$_GET['user']`, `$password` to `$_GET['password'], and compare. Also, should always use `var_dump(...);` to debug

Comment: @ajreal, I gave that a shot, I tried it with the POST and GET superglobals, but no luck. I pasted my modified version of your code and its subsequent output. Does this make any sense?

Comment: @Casey Flynn - Which operating system are you using ? And any possible for you to post your `UserData.txt` into the question and like `<pre>...</pre>`, I suspect is some control character or special characters break the matching. **OR** you can try to `var_dump($arr[0], $arr[1]);`

Comment: @ajreal, thanks for the suggestion of trying var_dump($arr[0], $arr[1]); I figured out that there was a trailing whitespace character after $arr[1]. I used trim() on the variables and the code works perfectly. I only dabble with PHP from time to time so I'm a bit shaky on all the fine details. :)

Answer (score 1):

`fgets` reads the final newline, so the password for `"test"` would be `"pass\n"`. Next time you have an issue like this one, use `var_dump` on the compared strings and carefully examine the output.

Either way, consider this:

```
$accounts = array();
foreach (file("UserData.txt",FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) as $line) {
  list($user,$pass) = explode(':',$line);
  $accounts[$user] = $pass;
}

if ($accounts[$the_user] === $the_password) { /* Password is correct */ }
```

Comment: ah. you beat me by seconds (-: Note that your solution overwrites the `$user` variable (that the poster neglected to show as input).

Comment: @scoates : which is why I use `$the_user` below ;-)

Comment: sure. just wanted it to be clear to the OP that he needs to look out for this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an off-by-one error.

Try:

```
while($line = fgets($fh)) { // or better, use file()
    list($u, $p) = explode(':', $line, 2);
    $accounts[$u] = $p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd rather read the entire file into an array:

```
$file = file('userdata.txt') or die("Can't open file");
```

After that, you can use `explode()` to split each line and add the user and password to the accounts array:

```
foreach($file as $line){
    $up = explode(':', $line);
    // here you can also check line validity
    if(count($up)!=2){
        continue; // skip it
    }
    $accounts[ trim($up[0]) ] = trim($up[1]);
}
```

Now the easy part:

```
if(isset($accounts[$user]) && $accounts[$user]===$password){
    echo "Welcome, $user"; // this should be sanitized before use
}
else{
    echo "Wrong username or password";
}
```

Comment: I didn't used `list()` because it can raise notices on invalid lines.